# How to use DataGridView in parallel.For?

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing

This is part of my program:

```
Parallel.For(1, m,
            Sub(i)
                
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

 Dim html As String = ""

 Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(slink(i, 1))

 request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip

 request.Timeout = 500

 request.Method = "GET"

  request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"

 Using response As Task(Of WebResponse) = request.GetResponseAsync

 If response.Result IsNot Nothing Then

  Using ioStream As IO.Stream = response.Result.GetResponseStream

 Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(ioStream)

                                    html = sr.ReadToEnd

                                    s = html.Split(";")
         
                                    r = s(0).Split(",")

  row = New String() {r(0),r(1),r(2),r(3),r(4),r(5)}

 DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
                                        DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

                           End Using

                            End Using

                        End If

                    End Using
              
            End Sub)
```

When I run the program, the following error occurs. How can I fix this?

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'DataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Think you possibly want to re-think your strategy a little.  Rather than update the DataGridView in threads, you would likely be better writing to the backing data source for that DataGridView then maybe do a single refresh of the DVG after your parallel.for

Comment: The issue should be pretty obvious. Parallel operations are performed on background threads and only the UI thread can access the UI, which includes your grid. You would need to get the data from the grid into some other data structure first, process that in parallel, then update your grid. If you have a `DataTable` bound to the grid, even processing that directly in the background will cause an issue, because any changes to that will be reflected in the grid and that will cause a cross-thread exception. In short, anything that affects the UI MUST be done on the UI thread only.

Comment: @Hursey Thanks for your comment. Only the full execution time of the parallel takes 45 seconds. If we use of DGV  after parallel, then , after the  45 seconds will show the information in the DVG itself, but if DVG can be placed inside the parallel, any URL that is examined will have its information in the DVG and we will not waste time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for your comment. In my program, we take information from several sites at the same time and I want to show this information in DVG at the same time.Is it possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible but you can't touch the grid in a background thread. You can gather the data from as many sources as you want and package it up on a background thread, but then you must load it into the grid on the UI thread. Based on what you're doing, you have two main choices. You can either run the parallel tasks and load the data into a data structure (e.g. a `DataTable`) first and then load that into the grid, or you can marshal a call to the UI thread from inside the parallel tasks to update the grid on the UI thread. If it's OK to update the grid at the end, do the former.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I want  to  marshal a call to the UI thread from inside the parallel tasks to update the grid on the UI thread. Please advise me what codes or functions I should use?

Comment: @jmcilhinney   When I use "begin invoke", the information  of all URL show in DGV at the end of the parallel, but I want each URL that is downloaded to show information  the same of URL  in DVG at the same time not at the end of the program.

Comment: That's because you're calling `Parallel.For` itself on the UI thread, which I failed to account for. If you call that on a background thread, e.g. in the `DoWork` event handler of a `BackgroundWorker`, then the UI thread will be free to execute those invocations.

Comment: @jmcilhinney   Please advise me how  to write these codes? thank you

Comment: If you want to use a `BackgroundWorker` then go and research how to use a `BackgroundWorker`. That is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest option would be to replace these lines:

```vb
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
```

with this:

```vb
DataGridView1.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                              DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
                              DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                          End Sub)
```

To understand more about how that works and how use a consistent step-by-step process to marshal a call to the UI thread, see [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387).